# Переход на другой экран после снимка с камеры! whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Я новичок в swift, и я пытаюсь написать приложение, которое будет извлекать фото с камеры в другой xib. При открытии камеры xcode ругается ошибкой

> Attempt to present MasterPhotoPost: 0x103311e60 on MenuView: 0x103203580 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Вот мой код

```
func showMasterPost(){
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialVC = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MasterPhotoPost")
    self.present(initialVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

 func doActionButton1() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: showMasterPost)
    }else{
        print("Нет доступа к камере")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211295/3004003

Comment: Благодарю. Сам разобрался.

Comment: @Дмитрий укажите ваш ответ, покалуйста

Comment: @RecursiveDaun ответил ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правда, появилось предупреждение 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0
А в остальном пока всё сделано через костыли, сильно не кидайтесь помидорами в меня за это)))

```
func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    var topMostViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while let presentedViewController = topMostViewController?.presentedViewController {
        topMostViewController = presentedViewController
    }
    return topMostViewController
}


func showMasterPost(){
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialVC = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MasterPhotoPost")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.getTopMostViewController()?.present(initialVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

func openCamera(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        print("Нет доступа к камере")
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: showMasterPost)
```